# Slicing a string into a list based on reoccuring patterns

Tags: python

I have a long string variable full of hex values:

`hexValues = 'AA08E3020202AA08E302AA1AA08E3020101'` etc..

The first `2 bytes (AA08)` are a signature for the start of a frame and the rest of the data up to the next AA08 are the contents of the signature.

I want to slice the string into a list based on the reoccurring start of frame sign, e.g:

`list = [AA08, E3020202, AA08, F25S1212, AA08, 42ABC82]` etc...

I'm not sure how I can split the string up like this. Some of the frames are also corrupted, where the start of the frame won'y have `AA08`, but maybe `AA01`.. so I'd need some kind of regex to spot these.

if I do `list = hexValues.split('AA08)'`, the list just removes all the starts of the frame...

So I'm a bit stuck.

Newbie to python.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The only way we can help you here is if you have some particular problem and/or error. We are not going to code a solution for you. I don't think your problem is *being new to python*, python doesn't do magic if you don't know how to program a solution. Try having a go yourself, and if you struggle in some part, come back with a concrete question.

Comment: Surely you can get the desired list from the result of the split. Having every other element be `'AA08'` conveys no information. If you want every other element to be `'AA08'` just do it.

Comment: Agreed with both of the above, and additionally: what signifies a "corrupted" frame besides `AA01`? You didn't sound confident about where the string needs to be split.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo You make a good point. I created an answer before I read your input. Will take it into account next time. Would be petty to remove my answer now.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen There is really nothing wrong with answering the question (specially if your answer is pretty cool and could benefit others, +1). I just think that in this particular scenario the OP will come tomorrow with another similar question. He just tried a single method from the documentation expecting some magic.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I'm here to learn and am not expecting grand solutions. Nor was I expecting any 'magic'... I've been trying different ways to go about the problem but all in vain so I came here to get a different perspective on how to go about it.. that is all. This has helped me greatly and I will learn from it. No need to make assumptions about my intentions.

Answer (score 2):

For the case when you don't have "corrupted" data the following should do:

```
hex_values = 'AA08E3020202AA08E302AA1AA08E3020101'
delimiter = hex_values[:4]
hex_values = hex_values.replace(delimiter, ',' + delimiter + ',')
hex_list = hex_values.split(',')[1:]
print(hex_list)


['AA08', 'E3020202', 'AA08', 'E302AA1', 'AA08', 'E3020101']
```

Comment: That is an elegant way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering corruptions, you may try this.

```
l = []
for s in hexValues.split('AA08'):
    if s:
        l += ['AA08', s]
```